# Ruby/Rails/Mysql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I am on leopard. It comes with Ruby 1.8 & Sqlite3 pre-installed. I have updated ruby to 1.9.1 & added Mysql. Here's the problem. I cannot get the path to correctly point to ruby 1.9.1. I tried to update the sym-link to no avail. I am able to get into Mysql from the terminal but I cannot connect to the server through Ruby because Sqlite3 is the default. I changed the database in my apps config file but it still doesn't work. Something is really screwing this up. I want to unistall every version of Ruby, Rails, All Gems, Mysql, Sqlite3, etc & roll all of what I want on my own. Where can I find the commands through the command line to do this? Can I just send these files to the trash manually as I find them on /usr/local/....? I am really frustrated at this point! please help.

Comment: "I cannot get the path to correctly point to ruby 1.9.1"

Which path? Ruby? `ruby -v` is not printing out 1.9.1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re-installing those packages will still not guarantee that its going to work. I would recommend go through the logs and see if you pick up some something obvious. There are lots of debugging techniques available for a Rails app, for starters see [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html)

Here's a small ruby snippet to see if the connection to MySQL works fine, give it a try if you see the MySQL server version being printed on your terminal then you know the problem is somewhere else, do not forget to change the credentials.

```
   #!/usr/bin/ruby -w

   require "mysql"

   begin
   # connect to the MySQL server
   dbh = Mysql.real_connect("localhost", "testuser", "testpass", "test")
   # get server version string and display it
   puts "Server version: " + dbh.get_server_info
   rescue Mysql::Error => e
     puts "Error code: #{e.errno}"
     puts "Error message: #{e.error}"
     puts "Error SQLSTATE: #{e.sqlstate}" if e.respond_to?("sqlstate")
   ensure
   # disconnect from server
   dbh.close if dbh
 end
```

Also if possible please provide some more details about the environment you are using, like

Apache + Rails + Mongrel  or 
Apache + Rails + Passenger etc

a snippet of your app/config/database.yml etc

If you are frustrated, take a break , relax, have a coffee  :-) and then start over again....working in a frustrated state of mind is definitely not going to help solve problems.

HTH